# Do different versions of iOS require different methods of iOS over-the-air distribution?

Tags: ios, ota, enterprise-distribution

I have created an iOS app with Cordova targeting iOS 4.3 and up.  I am using enterprise OTA to distribute the app.  The app is installed on a server with a link to the plist file as follows.

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=http://ww7.mysite.com/mobile/MyAppName.plist" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration: underline; font-size: xx-large; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; color: #FF9900">Install App</a>
```

The app installs fine on iOS 6.  On iOS 4.3 and 5.1 I am receiving the error "cannot connect to ww7.mysite.com"

When I use the iPhone Configuration Utility to look at the console when attempting to install the app I see the following error.

"Mar 26 11:00:00 iPhone itunesstored[302] : Could not load download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=1 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x1c5645f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}"

Comment: The OTA distribution mechanism and plist format has been very stable since iOS 4. You should not see an error like this assuming you have set everything up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that during my build, when I reached the "Save For Enterprise" step which creates the .plist and .ipa file I was renaming the .ipa file. It looks like iOS 6 handled this renaming okay, while earlier versions of iOS would not accept a different name. Saving the .ipa file with the default name solved the problem.